# Error when trying to migrate postgresql db to mysql with workbench

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mysql-workbench, psql, psqlodbc

I am trying to migrate a postgresql database to mysql following this tutorial:  http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/11/how-to-migrate-postgresql-databases-to-mysql-using-the-mysql-workbench-migration-wizard/

I am experiencing this error when I try to test my connection

> Could not connect to Source DBMS [IM002][Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Data soure name not found and no default driver specified
>   (0)(SQLDriverConnect)

ODBC connection string

```
Driver=psqlodc;SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=5432;DATA...
```

Does anyone know how to correct this error?

Comment: Do you already installed postgresql driver on your system?

Comment: Yes I already installed psqlodbc driver psqlodbc_09_03_0300.zip from herer:  http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

Comment: You need to test some: - Check the database accept remote connections over TC, - Check if your password is correct

Comment: I have checked already, have been struggling with this all day

Comment: From deleted answer: The driver names are: `Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI}` (32-bit ANSI codepage),
`Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode}` (32-bit UTF-16 Unicode),
`Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)}` (64-bit ANSI codepage),
`Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)}` (64-bit UTF-16 Unicode).

Comment: `Driver=psqlodc;` 
shouldn't that be `psqlodbc`?

Comment: @heliotrope in my case both psqlodbc adn psqlODBC does not works.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I was using Windows 64bit and using "PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)" did connect to the Postgres database but it gave errors while migrating the database from Postgres to Mysql. I used the driver "PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)" and it worked. If your data contains unicode characters i.e. non ASCII characters use "PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)" drivers.
[image]

Comment: PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)  did the job for me

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same error. Here is how I solved it:

1. I downloaded the drivers from https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/ (Select the most recent one for x64)
2. In the Overview form, click on the button "Open ODBC Administrator". Add the recently installed "PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)". Click "Finish".
3. When you "Start Migration", in the source selection form, use "Driver: PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)"

Answer (score 2):

Just quoting Craig Ringer's comment to make it "more visible"

If you have Windows 64Bits then you probably had installed only the 64bit psqlodbc drivers, so all you need is to use e.g.: `PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)` (I had used that and worked for me)

Just stuck onto it for at least 1h until came into Craig's comment, Thanks man!

Comment: It is working for me i just changed  PostgreSQL ANSI to PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)

Answer (score 2):

For those on Ubuntu install the postgres ODBC drivers:

```
apt-get install odbc-postgresql
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the official documentation from [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-postgresql-drivers-linux.html), in which they tell you to set up you `ODBC` connection as

`Name: 'psqlODBC'`

This is now the name of the `driver`. So whatever you have called the name in `ODBC` will need to match your `Driver` inside `Workbench`

[image]
<sup>*Name `psqlODBC`*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*Matches Driver here `psqlODBC`*</sup>

And then hopefully you'll get:

[image]

Comment: that "name" from Mysql Workbench must be the same as name in ODBC - that was my problem!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (w/ ODBC installed):

1. Click "*Open ODBC Administrator*" button
2. Go to "*Drivers*" tab
3. Copy the "*Name*" Column value from your ODBC and close popup
4. In tab "*Parameters*", "*Driver*" field, Past the "*Name*" copied
5. Test connection

Answer (score -3):

Download and install the MSI package for psqlODBC from 
http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/ .

Then connect using the following settings  
Driver: PostgreSQL ANSI  
Connection method: ODBC (Manually entered parameters)  
This worked for me.

Comment: This does not work. Can you add a little more detail on how this worked for you? How you installed it? What file you downloaded? Version?32 bit? 64bit? Please add more details, I have been struggling on this.

Comment: same comment as above, this answer is so random