# Syntax error on MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on migrating a PostgreSQL database to a MySQL environment using the MySQL Workbench migration wizard.

I have trouble when connecting to PostgreSQL, which is located on localhost.

I'm using `ODBC(manually entered parameters)` methods and my parameters are like these:

```
DRIVER=psqlODBC;SERVER=localhost;PORT=5432;DATABASE=my_database_name;UID=my_user_name;UseDeclareFetch=1;
```

And here is the result of test connection:

> Could not connect to Source DBMS. []  (1) (SQLExecDirectW)

Also, I got these logs from PostgreSQL:

```
2019-03-08 14:17:29.223 JST [92718] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "S" at character 7
2019-03-08 14:17:29.223 JST [92718] STATEMENT:  BEGIN;S
2019-03-08 14:17:29.237 JST [92747] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "s" at character 7
2019-03-08 14:17:29.237 JST [92747] STATEMENT:  BEGIN;s
2019-03-08 14:17:29.252 JST [92747] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "S" at character 7
2019-03-08 14:17:29.252 JST [92747] STATEMENT:  BEGIN;S
2019-03-08 14:17:29.267 JST [92748] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "s" at character 7
2019-03-08 14:17:29.267 JST [92748] STATEMENT:  BEGIN;s
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when trying to migrate postgresql db to mysql with workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199390/error-when-trying-to-migrate-postgresql-db-to-mysql-with-workbench)

Comment: I've already checked that post and I think that's not with my case. I installed psqlODBC driver following [this instruction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-postgresql-drivers-linux.html) and still got problem...